# Just after updating a page, is there any action that I should do for google indexing?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have found out that one of my pages has weak SEO and shows in the later pages of google. So I modified my page a little and added some description etc. Now is there a way to tell google that I have updated this single page? I could not find it in webmaster tools? Did I miss it ?

Comment: In GWT you can manually submit a page to be indexed... http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/39612/1243

Answer (score 2):

Few of things you can do:

1 - On Webmaster Tools, Go to "Health" / "Fetch as Google" where you can enter the address of the page that has changed, click on "Fetch" then click on "Submit to index". At which point a message will pop up and say: "Select if your page is new or has been recently updated. Google doesn't guarantee to index all submitted URLs." Choose your option, and hit OK.

2 - Resubmit sitemap.

3 - Adjust crawl frequency.

```
I always go to step 1 when I change something on a page.
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot will recrawl soon, so there is generally nothing you *need* to do.  How soon depends on the pagerank of the page.  Here are some rough guidelines about how long it might take googlebot to return.

- pagerank 0: 3 weeks
- pagerank 2: 10 days
- pagerank 4: 4 days
- pagerank 6: 1 day
- pagerank 8: 1 hour

You might be able to get googlebot to come back faster by bringing the page to its attention.  I know that for *new* pages, you can tweet about the page on Twitter.  Then googlebot will crawl it right away.  I haven't tried getting Googlebot to return to an updated page with a tweet, but that might work as well.

Comment: Stephen where are you getting those figures? I'd be interested in reading more

Comment: Personal experience.  I worked with a pr 8 site where the homepage was crawled hourly.   Googlebot crawl rate seems directly proportional to pagerank on a page level.

Comment: I don't think PR necessarily has a direct correlation to how often Google crawls the site / new pages. Webmasters homepage appears to have a PR of 6, and new pages are crawled within minutes. PR is attributed to pages, not sites and new pages don't have PR.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about return crawl rate.  New pages are generally crawled as soon as they are found.  Googlebot revisits pages that are already crawled based on their pagerank.  If you friend has a PR 6 homepage, and links to new pages in several places, the new page will likely be found very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In Webmaster tool, add the updated link in your existing sitemap.xml and re-submit it.

Otherwise, If your site is a blog, you can use pingomatic.com. So it will ping your site to the major blog search engines.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But re-submit'in the sitemap.xml is like a reset, and whenever I did it before, my indexed pages droped to zero and restarted to increasing ? am I wrong?

Comment: Re-Submitting a sitemap is a way submitting google to re-index the pages. If your pages is getting dropped means, that may be the wrong in your SEO process.